The Fibonacci sequence: ratio of mature to young rabbit pairs within each generation also converges on the Golden Ratio (online or other reference?)
In looking at the breeding rabbit pair model which lies behind the Fibonacci sequence, one observes  that for any given population of A(n) adult pairs (breeding) and Y(n) young pairs (non-breeding) in the nth generation, the relationship between the composition of the nth and (n+1)th generation is:
nth generation: A(n) adult pairs and Y(n) young pairs, F(n) = A(n) + Y(n)
(n+1)th generation: A(n+1) = A(n) + Y(n) adult pairs, Y(n+1) = A(n) young pairs, F(n+1) = A(n+1)+Y(n+1)
It doesn't matter if one starts with A(1) = 0 and Y(1) = 1 (as in the Figure) to generate the classic Fibonacci sequence (1,1,2,3,5, etc.) or some other arbitrary set of initial values for adult and young pairs, the ratio of adult to young pairs within each successive generation converges on the same number – the Figure is a spreadsheet of the first 20 generations, where the last column is the Fibonacci number:

Although the convergence of the ratio F(n+1):F(n) on the Golden Ratio is well-known, I've not yet found a reference to the fact that ratio of adult-to-young pair numbers within successive generations also converges on the Golden Ratio – I'd appreciate it if anyone can provide a web resource (or some other reference) featuring this result?

Look at your table! The adult and young numbers are successive Fibonacci numbers so their ratio is ...

The comment about arbitrary starting conditions is correct for integer (even rational) nonzero starting conditions, but for $A(0) = \bar\phi Y(0)$, $\bar\phi := \frac12 (1 - \sqrt 5)$ (and $Y(0) \neq 0$), the ratio $F(n + 1) : F(n)$ is $\bar\phi$ for all $n$ and so doesn't approach the Golden Ratio. Of course, that initial condition is not physically meaningful!

Point taken @TravisWillse (I should have excluded the starting conditions you've identified) - also, model itself is completely unrealistic, i.e. rabbits that never die and breed forever!

Thank you @EthanBolker - I now see the adult and young pair numbers for a given n are F(n-1) and F(n-2), respectively. I'm just surprised that I've not come across an online (or other) reference to the Golden Ratio's appearance as the limit for the adult/young ratio as n tends to infinity, not just the limit ratio of successive Fibonacci numbers.

Since the numbers are the same it's not worth the time to make the separate observation about the limit of the ratios.
